# What does natural man or natural woman mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases, lyrics

Songs like "You Make me Feel Like a Natural Woman" and "Kisses Sweeter than Wine" use this phrase. "I begged her and I pleaded like a natural man..." in Kisses Sweeter than Wine.

In theology the concept of natural man seems to refer to a sinful nature not yet redeemed by God's grace. In the songs, the state of being natural seems to be a positive thing. The context suggests it means direct and free from affectation or pretention.

Answer (score 2):

These are song lyrics.  They are meant to sound good when sung, but don't have to mean much.

"You make me feel like a natural woman" suggests "you make me feel the way that women are supposed to feel" (not stressed or tired)  In contrast to how she feels in her working life, when she has to pretend to be something that she isn't.  She can feel relaxed and natural with this man.

And "pleaded like a natural man" suggests "like it is natural and normal for a man to plead" (when he is asking his girlfriend to marry him)

There is nothing here about theology.

(and not much that is useful to apply to learning English, since you can't use these phrases outside of songs).